# Is it possible to include a Fragment in an input method layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-input-method

Is it possible to include a `Fragment` as part of an input method (IME)?

The trouble is that my input method has to `extends InputMethodService` which means it isn't a `FragmentActivity`

Comment: Did u found any solution or work around for this issue...please guide if if u had. Thank you in advance :)